# Redis does not start on boot on homestead vagrant server

Tags: laravel, homestead

I know that we can directly ssh into the VM & enable the redis service.
But i think there must be a way to enable redis using `homestead.yaml`. 
I tried to search for docs but i couldn't find anything.

EDIT

I'm posting my `homestead.yaml` file.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 1048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\stack\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\stack\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: W:\sites\project
      to: /home/vagrant/project

sites:
    - map: project.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

I have installed `predis` so the connection with redis is not an issue.
Everytime i boot my vm, I manually have to go & start redis by typing this command `systemctl start redis-server`.

Which is the reason i was wondering that there must be a way to enable redis server from inside the `homestead.yaml` so i don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want homestead's redis server to start automatically whenever homestead is up...

1. Log into homestead via ssh.
2. `sudo systemctl enable redis-server`

You should only need to run this once.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is already included/installed thus enabled in Homestead. See [included softwares of Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#included-software).

To test type `redis-cli` and `ping` in your command line (inside vagrant)

For predis just run [`composer require predis/predis`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redis#introduction).

Answer (score 1):

There was a [Bug](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1328) with this version of Homestead `10.0.1`

> Redis does not start on boot.

However this has been fixed if you check out the issue i have linked.

---

## Still an issue?

Here is a quick fix while waiting for homestead box update

```
sudo service redis-server start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **services** section to your homestead.yaml after **features** section, but I don't know if order matters.

```
services:
- enabled:
      - "redis-server"
```

Then `vagrant reload --provision`